# Assign Icons to specific points dynamically in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, features, style

I have a json file describing features on a map (routes, points etc)

points include places of interest such as airport, harbor etc.

Is there a way to assign icons to these points?

example: have a path to an icon in my json file as an attribute to that point and request that that icon be used as a marker for that point?

I used the advice below by @Aragon, still can't get it to work..

my json looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "id0",
        "properties": {
            "graphic": "../../icons/pushpin.png",
            "title": "blah",
            "transportation": "Blah",
            "description": "blah"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                24.067939338686,
                35.525197669582
            ]
        },
        "crs": {
            "type": "name",
            "properties": {
                "name": "EPSG: 900913"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

and my javascript looks like this:

```
 var context = {
        getGraphic: function(feature) {                    
            return feature.attributes.graphic;
        }
    };
    var template = {
        'externalGraphic': '${getGraphic}',
        'graphicWidth' :15,
        'graphicHeight':15,
        'fillColor':'#669933',
        'fillOpacity':.8,
        'strokeColor':'red',
        'strokeWidth':5,
        'pointRadius':6

    };
            var data_vector_style = new OpenLayers.Style(template, {context: context});

            // Style Map tells vector Layer what style objects to use when features are
            //  in a certain state (states can be default, select or temporary
            var data_style_map = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default':data_vector_style});
            var dataLayer =  new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("My GeoJson data from server", {
                projection:  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                styleMap : data_style_map
            });


            var features = getFeatures("../../controller?action=GET_USER_LOCATIONS");
            //alert(features);
            dataLayer.addFeatures(features);
```

if I change any of the other styling in template, it works fine. if I hardcode the marker in the styling    **'externalGraphic': '../../icons/pushpin.png'**, it works fine. when I try to use attribute replacement the marker isn't used... Am I doing it wrong in the json object?

Answer (score 5):

you can do this with some ways:

- defining context style:

> context
>
> {Object} An optional object with properties that symbolizers’ property
>   values should be evaluated against.  If no context is specified,
>   feature.attributes will be used. you
>
> you can check out [here](http://openflights.org/blog/2009/10/21/customized-openlayers-cluster-strategies/) for some idea.

```
       var context = {
            getGraphic: function(feature) {                    
                return feature.attributes.url;
            }
        };
        var template = {
            externalGraphic: "${getGraphic}"

        };
        var style = new OpenLayers.Style(template, {context: context});
        var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Points', {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(style),
            renderers: renderer
        });
        layer.addFeatures(features);

        map.addLayer(layer);
```

- defining marker when adding all points from json for icon style:

  ```
      var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
      map.addLayer(markers);

      var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
      var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
      var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png',
                 size, offset);
      markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0,0),icon));
      markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0,0),icon.clone()));
  ```
- change it after adding to map:

  ```
       // Define Marker Layer Here
       var feat = vectorLayer.features;
       for(var a = 0; a < feat.length; a++){
          var iconAdress = feat[a].attributes.url;

          marker.icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(iconAdress , size, offset);
          marker.icon.size = size;
          marker.icon.offset = offset;             
       };
       marker.draw();
  ```
- using marker setUrl method [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html#OpenLayers.Marker.setUrl)

  ```
       markers.setUrl('newSRCAdres');
  ```

  i hope it helps you..

Comment: WOW that was really quick! I've been trying to make it work but no luck so far.. my style is  var data_vector_style = new OpenLayers.Style({
 'externalGraphic': 'icons/transportation_plane.png'}); and I'd like to use context to solve my problem but I can't really get the hang of it.. :S

Comment: Don't forget to include size for your icon, it's critical

Comment: you are right @Vadim. For the example given above, probably understandable... :)

Comment: My advice was for @chri_chri's comment since she only had the img URL in the style object.

Comment: @Aragon would you mind taking another look at my edit? it must be something trivial I am getting wrong... :/

Comment: check out: `yourLayerNAME.features[0].attributes.graphic` is whether correct or not and dont forget to control your icon adress right `return  dir + feature.attributes.graphic`